# How do identify a USB modem /dev on LINUX with Python

Tags: python, linux, usb

If I have a USB modem that I  am accessing using Python pyserial module, it requires the device to be identified '/dev/ttyACM0 for example. If the modem is attached to a USB hub it no longer appears in /dev/tty...

How do identify it programmatically from my Python code so regardless of whether it has been changed or not, or the machine rebooted I can locate the modem?

Note:
I can always see the device using lsusb, but if it is attached to a USB hub it does not appear as /dev/tty... device

Comment: It's hard to try and automatically find the right modem. What if you have two connected for example? The device path can be put in some kind of configuration variable (configuration file and/or command line argument) so it can easily be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the linux kernel. If you can, try a more recent version.

If that fails, check the last few lines of the output of `dmesg` or in the file `/var/log/messages` (the latter depends on your distribution; if that file doesn't exist or doesn't contain what you're looking for, then check the other files in `/var/log`; sorting by time with `ls -rt` helps).

After identifying the device, you might see a pattern.

Another approach is the major and minor number. If you run `ls -l /dev`, you'll see output like this:

```
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,   0 2011-12-19 09:15 tty0
```

The `c` means "character device" and the `4, 0` means it's the console device unit 0.

The `4` is the major number which identifies the type of device. See `/proc/devices` for a list of major numbers and the respective device drivers.

If you plug in the model directly, note the major number. After plugging it into a hub, try to find devices with the same number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes - it is a character device. I have tried making before and after files and diff-ing them, also grep-ed model number. The modem is definitely not there when attached to the hub. I am going to buy another hub and try that.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 10.10 with 2.6.35-22-generic Kernel on i686

Comment: Try a different hub, first. They sometimes do have bugs. If that doesn't help, consider to upgrade to 11.10 or 11.04 - unless you're running LTS.

Comment: dmesg recognises the modem being attached but then I get a message 'rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power' - faulty hub I think

Comment: Eric: Ah! You need a powered hub (one with a power supply) because the modem uses it to power itself!

Comment: It is supposed powered, but I suspect it has a fault - hence a new purchase

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing some voodoo in Python, try writing a [udev rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) which gives your device a much more useful name like `/dev/my-serial-thingy`. Using that from Python is way easier.